# Why do I get an error, when I instantiating prefab second time?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, instantiation, gameobject

When I try to add a prefab to my instantiated gameobject, I get an error:

> Setting the parent of a transform which resides in a prefab is disabled to prevent data corruption

When I call this script for the first time, everything works fine. There are a lot of similar questions and answers. However, I could not solve my problem with them.

Thanks for the help :)

```cs
GameObject coralWoodBundle = Resources.Load("Base/coral_wood_bundle") as GameObject;
GameObject woodlBundle = Instantiate(coralWoodBundle) as GameObject;
woodlBundle.transform.SetParent(this.gameObject.transform);
```

---

**Related script**

```cs
public class FallingWoodPackScript: MonoBehaviour
{
    public List<FallingWoodScript> fallingWoodScripts;

    public void Start()
    {
        RefillWood();
    }

    public void RefillWood()
    {
        GameObject coralWoodBundle = Resources.Load("Base/coral_wood_bundle") as GameObject;
        GameObject woodlBundle = Instantiate(coralWoodBundle) as GameObject;
        woodlBundle.transform.SetParent(this.gameObject.transform);
        woodlBundle.transform.localPosition = new Vector3(1f, 2.7f, 0);
        woodlBundle.transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(new Vector3(0, 0, -90));
        fallingWoodScripts = new List<FallingWoodScript>();
        foreach (Transform child in woodlBundle.transform)
        {
            fallingWoodScripts.Add(child.GetComponent<FallingWoodScript>());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post the entire script?

Comment: i updated the description with the script.

Comment: Is the game object you're working with instantiated or is it always there (even before running on play mode)?

Comment: It is also a prefab that instantiated on play mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this error quite a while ago and in my opinion its phrasing is a bit misleading.

Maybe you understand it better like this:

> Setting the parent **TO** a transform which resides in a prefab is disabled to prevent data corruption

My guess here is that the `FallingWoodPackScript` reference (=`this`) you are calling `RefillWood` or `Start` via script on is actually a **Prefab reference** and therefore `this.gameObject.transform` is as the error says `a transform which resides in a prefab`.

Make sure you are calling the `RefillWood` (or `Start`) only on an actual **instance** in the scene.